# How can I unzip files in a child directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, extract, unzip

Say I have the following directories and files

```
/folder1/subdir/zip1.zip
/folder1/zip2.zip
/folder2/zip1.zip
/folder2/subdir/zip2.zip
```

If I am in `/`, how can I extract all `.zip` files quickly?

Edit:

The method must work on the Linux command line

Comment: "...must work on the Linux command line" - this sounds like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've added the last part because someone recommended WinRAR, which doesn't work on a cli-only Linux installation.

Comment: This should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107995/how-do-you-recursively-unzip-archives-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-from#2318189